# osmupdate between 2 timestamps (planet.openstreetmap.org)

Tags: ubuntu, timestamp, openstreetmap

I'm working on a OpenStreetMap project and I want to have a .osc file containing data between 2 timestamps with the command osmupdate.

For example `osmupdate NOW-3600 change_file.osc` works perfectly, and will give me all the data from the timestamp at this time and one hour in advance. But now I want to get data between 2 timestamps for example 2022-06-05T06:00:00Z and 2022-06-05T06:30:00Z (30 minutes difference).

`osmupdate 2022-07-06T09:30:00Z file.osc` also works perfectly and will give me a file containing the data starting from that timestamp until now. This is where I'm searching mostly: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmupdate, But I don't find a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: crosspost: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/osmupdate-between-2-timestamps-planet-openstreetmap-org/1917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible according to the wiki, you can choose between a given timestamp and now ...

source:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/diffs
[image]
"Alternatively, the osmupdate can be used to create cumulated diff files (.osc, .osc.gz, .o5c, .o5c.gz). The program will download all necessary diffs between a given timestamp and now."